# Why checkAndRepleaceImage method is not working?

Tags: android

As per requirement, I can't use TextInputLayout, and I want to show eyes option because it is for paasswordActivity.

So, I took one Image and trying to replace Image programatically, but it's not working!

when user click on eyes option, this method is calling:

```
checkAndRepleaceImage(createPasscodeVisibility);
```

And `createPasscodeVisibility` is a variable which I bind with xml ImageView ID.

```
protected void checkAndRepleaceImage(ImageView imageView) {
        showLog("current: " + imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState());
        showLog("expected: " + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp).isVisible());
        showLog("output: " + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_24dp).getConstantState());
        if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp).getConstantState()) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_24dp);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_24dp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the if condition works fine?

Comment: @MalavanRockzz problem has been fixed. Thanks for reply anyway. Can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303666/what-is-alternative-of-appcompat-button-borderless-in-materialcomponents ?

Comment: If it's solved, you should write the answer here. It will helpful for others with the same problem.