# What is alternative of AppCompat.Button.Borderless in MaterialComponents?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

Because of some requirement in my project, I must use MaterialComponents, so my previous UI is became messy, and I need to change it.

**previous Image with AppCompat:**

[image]

**new Image with MaterialComponents:**

[image]
Code:

```
<style name="ButtonBorderless" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

MainStyle:

```
<style name="DayTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Button:

```
<Button
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_interval_decrease"
                                    style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:text="-"
                                    android:textColor="?attr/icon_color"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Please note: There are two problems in this image:
1. borderless button
2.check the **WE** button, it's last part is cutting

Complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="@string/repeat"
                    android:textColor="?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch_repeat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_repeat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab_relative_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type">

                            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:clipToPadding="true"
                                app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_reminder_type"
                                app:tabGravity="fill"
                                app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                                app:tabMode="fixed"
                                app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
                                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
                                app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
                                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance">

                                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                    android:id="@+id/tab_daily"
                                    style="@style/tabItem"
                                    android:text="@string/tab_daily" />

                                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                    android:id="@+id/tab_weekly"
                                    style="@style/tabItem"
                                    android:text="@string/tab_weekly" />

                                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                    android:id="@+id/tab_monthly"
                                    style="@style/tabItem"
                                    android:text="@string/tab_monthly" />

                                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                    android:id="@+id/tab_yearly"
                                    style="@style/tabItem"
                                    android:text="@string/tab_yearly" />
                            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/weekdays_error"
                        layout="@layout/row_error_textview" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_repeat_interval"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/repeat_daily"
                            android:textColor="?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                            app:cardElevation="0dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_repeat_reminder"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_interval_increase"
                                    style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:text="+"
                                    android:textColor="?attr/icon_color"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                                <View
                                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="?attr/toolbar_color" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_interval_decrease"
                                    style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:text="-"
                                    android:textColor="?attr/icon_color"
                                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spin_list"
                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            android:backgroundTint="?attr/icon_color"
                            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="17dp"
                            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_end_date"
                            style="@style/ButtonBorderless"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:hint="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="?attr/day_colorDarkGray_night_colorWhite"
                            android:visibility="visible" />


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/error_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_days"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="?attr/cardbackgroundColor">

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleSunday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="SU"
                                android:textOn="SU"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleMonday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="MO"
                                android:textOn="MO"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleTuesday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="TU"
                                android:textOn="TU"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleWednesday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="WE"
                                android:textOn="WE"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleThursday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="TH"
                                android:textOn="TH"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleFriday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="FR"
                                android:textOn="FR"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />

                            <ToggleButton
                                android:id="@+id/toggleSaturday"
                                android:layout_width="45dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/selector_day_toggle"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/selector_day_text"
                                android:textOff="SA"
                                android:textOn="SA"
                                android:textSize="16dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <View style="@style/view_style" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/layout_repeat"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/layout_repeat"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhiteTransparent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)?

Comment: yes, 100 times. but according to my code, I'm not solving it. In short my whole project is in MaterialComponents now, and I fixed some other things, but this is not solved

Comment: use app:strockwidth="0dp" in materialbutton tag

Comment: okay, I change from buttton to Material button and I put that line but no effect

Comment: How do you manage the WE circle button?

Comment: Instead of taking different _ToggleButtons_ you should use _RecyclerView_ with _GridLayoutManager_. That will be more optimized

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Please check my updated question, as I added complete XML.

Comment: @PriyankaSingh Too complex. Just try a simple layout with only the toggleButtons of the weeks.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that this is the equivalent of borderless button.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` for best practice if you use Material Components

https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-buttons-76fa1a92ec0a

```
      <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
          android:id="@+id/toggleGroup2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          app:checkedButton="@id/btnA"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:singleSelection="true">

          <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
              android:id="@+id/btnA"
              style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
              app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
              android:text="+" />

          <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
              android:id="@+id/btnS"
              style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:text="-" />

      </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving me full code. And what about that WE button which is cutting from right side because of dialog size with new effect of MaterialComponents?

Comment: Your parent container is fix width or its wrap? it would be more nice if you add that xml.

Comment: That MaterialButtonToggleGroup work perfect as per your needs ?

Comment: I will add that. and please check my updated question

Comment: Can you wrap this  android:id="@+id/layout_days" LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout

Comment: Else you have to manage this fix height and width for all device with different dimension. Test with different device high resolution it will not cut

Comment: This solves OP's problem, but people will still arrive at this question seeking a borderless button when a togglegroup doesn't apply to their situation at all